# Unable to run jar file with --enable-preview flag when using corretto 17

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2, corretto

I am trying to run my application in an `ec2` instance using the command

`nohup java --enable-preview my-application.jar`

But somehow the `--enable-preview` flag is ignored and i still get an error on startup telling me that i should try running it with the flag `--enable-preview`. I use amazon's `corretto-17` as the openJDK version.

Does `corretto-17` not support the `--enable-preview` flag? The `jar` file runs fine when i run it in `Intellij IDEA` with `--enable-preview`. I've also added this flag as a compile argument to my `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by `nohup`. Apparently java arguments are ignored when you execute the jar file while also using the supplemental command `nohup`.